# How can I get selected values in multi-select dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a page that uses the ASP.NET MVC razor engine with the following sample code for a multi-select dropdownlist

```
<td>
@Html.DropDownList("ddlMyList", ViewBag.MyList as IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>, "[ALL]", new { @multiple = "multiple" })                    
</td>
```

My problem is how to get all the selected  values from the dropdownlist in the code below

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult GenerateStandardReport(FormCollection frm)
        {

                int mySelectedListItems;
                string reportType = string.Empty;
                string startDate = string.Empty;
                string endDate = string.Empty;

                //HOW CAN I GET A SINGLE OR ALL MULTIPLE VALUES SELECTED IN 
                //DROPDOWNLIST HERE?

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(frm["reportType"]))
                {
                    reportType = frm["reportType"];
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(frm["startDate"]))
                {
                    startDate = frm["startDate"];
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(frm["endDate"]))
                {
                    endDate = frm["endDate"];
                }
}
```

Comment: send as array of values to your provided code.

Comment: `$('select option:selected').each( function () { $('#target').append($(this).val() )});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still very new to ASP.NET MVC and this Razor stuff & jQuery stuff but for some reason, i tried the code below just works. I cant to figure out why it works though, time to do some reading.

```
 string drp1 = string.Empty;
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(frm["ddlMyList"]))
    {
       drp1 = frm["ddlMyList"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this it maybe helpful to you

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult GenerateStandardReport(Model modelinstance)
    {

            string selectedValue = modelinstance.ddlMyList;
}
```